# Controlling a matlab script (Pause, Reset)

Tags: matlab, loops, controls

I am trying to create a matlab script (m-file) which shall be controlled by an external VBA script.

The matlab script shall do the same operation every time (even params change, but this is not the matter in this case) for a certain number of loops.
If I see it right, I can use matlab funktions in VBA like this: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html#f133975

My main problem is how to implement the matlab part of this problem...at the moment my control part looks like this:

**start.m:**

```
run = 1;
reset = 0;
while run ~= 0     % Loop until external reset of 'run' to '0'
    if reset ~= 0
        doReset();   % Reset the parameters for the processing
        reset = 0;
        disp('I did a reset');
    end

    disp('I am processing');
    doProcess();
    pause(1)
end
disp('I am done');
```

The reset part works very fine while changing the value by the script, but when I manually try to change the value of 'run' or 'reset' to any other value in my workspace, nothing happens...my script doen't abort, neither does the reset-if do it's work...
this seems to me that the script doesn't recognize any changes in the workspace?!

later the variables 'run' and 'reset' shall be set or unset by the VBA script.
Is there any plausible reason why I can't abort the loop by hand?

Thanks for any advice!

greets, poeschlorn

**Edit:**

It seems that the script loads the variables once before starting and never again during runtime...is there a possibility to have explicit access to a workspace variable?

**Edit 2:**

I use Matlab 2010b with no additional Toolboxes at the moment

**Edit 3:**

I found out, that there are several 'workspaces' or RAMs in Matlab. If my function is running, the variables are stored in 'base' (?) workspace, which is not the matlab workspace on which you can click and change every value. So I have to get access to this ominous 'base' space and change the flag 'run' to zero.

Comment: r.e. Edit 3: There is nothing ominous, functions have their own variable stack, and the workspace another (you don't want a user function changing your workspace variables and visa versa!). If you need to access a variable globally across the workspace and user functions, use the **global** keyword, i.e. `global run` in both your workspace and any function you use -- http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-38052.html#f0-38470 -- this is assuming your loop is not blocking the external interface...

Comment: @Edit 3: There is such a function: [`assigning`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/assignin.html) which is _very_ unrecommended.

Comment: @Juhl: Why is this function very unrecommended? I don't see any point against it O.o

Comment: It behaves pretty much the same way as globals, and takes it one step further by declaring variables in _others_ workspaces. No problem to use it if you are hacking away, but I would be aware of it when using it for larger programs etc.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your problem is simply that your loop is blocking execution of the external interface. While the loop runs you cannot access the other interfaces.

I wanted to do a similar thing -- allow control of a matlab loop by an external program (either Ruby or another matlab instance). The most flexible solution by far was using UDP. There is a great toolbox called PNET for matlab, and I assume VB must have a socket library too. I simply open a UDP port on both sides, and use simple text commands to control and give feedback.

```
obj.conn = pnet('udpsocket', 9999);
command = '';
while run ~= 0
    nBytes = pnet(obj.conn, 'readpacket');
    if nBytes > 0
        command = pnet(obj.conn, 'read', nBytes, 'string');
    end
    switch command
        case '--reset--'
            doReset();   % Reset the parameters for the processing
            reset = 0;
            disp('I did a reset');
        case '--abort--'
            run = 0;
            disp('Going to abort');
        case '--echo--'
            pnet(obj.conn, 'write', '--echo--');
            pnet(obj.conn, 'writepacket', remoteAddress, remotePort);
    end
    doProcess();
end
```

This way I can build my own extensible control interface without worrying about blocking from the loop, it can work cross-platform and cross-language, can work within a machine or across the network.

UPDATE:
To talk between two UDP clients, you need to set up two complimentary UDP ports, both are clients (this example is all in matlab, pretend obj here is a structure, in my case it is a class i wrap around the pnet functionality):

```
obj = struct();
obj.success = 0;
obj.client1Port = 9999;
obj.client2Port = 9998;
obj.client1Address = '127.0.0.1';
obj.client2Address = '127.0.0.1';
obj.conn1 = pnet('udpsocket', obj.client1Port);
obj.conn2 = pnet('udpsocket', obj.client2Port);

pnet(obj.conn1, 'write', '--echo--')
pnet(obj.conn1, 'writepacket', obj.client2Address, obj.client2Port);

nBytes = pnet(obj.conn2, 'readpacket');
if nBytes > 0
    command = pnet(obj.conn2, 'read', nBytes, 'string');
    if regexpi(command,'--echo--')
        obj.success = obj.success+1;
        fprintf('Client 2 recieved this message: %s\n',command);
        pnet(obj.conn2, 'write', '--echo--')
        pnet(obj.conn2, 'writepacket', obj.client1Address, obj.client1Port);
    end
end

nBytes = pnet(obj.conn1, 'readpacket');
if nBytes > 0
    command = pnet(obj.conn1, 'read', nBytes, 'string');
    if regexpi(command,'--echo--')
        obj.success = obj.success+1;
        fprintf('Client 1 got this back: %s\n',command);
    end
end

if obj.success == 2
    fprintf('\nWe both sent and received messages!\n');
end
```

Comment: Wow this is absolutely awesome. Can you tell me, where I can find the PNET library? It seem that Mathworks don't have those whole toolbox anywhere but some inofficial ones are ready to load...can you tell me which one you are using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using pnet which is already precompiled (for Win, OS X and Linux) from the psychophysics toolbox: [PTB](http://psychtoolbox.org/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage), you can download it and extract the directory, or scrape the svn [here](http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/osxptb/trunk/Psychtoolbox/PsychHardware/iViewXToolbox/tcp_udp_ip/?#a92ec166f430377948ced499fe2456e27) -- the toolbox itself is found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcpudpip-toolbox-2-0-6) -- you can use either TCP (reliable with more overhead) or UDP (connectionless and faster); UDP is easier to set up.

Comment: Note you can also use UDP directly in Matlab if you have the Instrument Control toolbox [documented here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/instrument/f16-54297.html). I **much** prefer PNET, as you can send not only simple data types, but even matlab oop objects, which otherwise would be close to impossible to serialise and send over the network (weakness of matlab itself). There is also a matlab java interface alternative to PNET [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525-a-simple-udp-communications-application)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I downloaded the correct files...I extracted them to the directory where the script of my loop also is in. Can you please point out, how the second script must look like in order to send a correct comand (e.g. --abort--)? I am not getting along with this (even using a secont instance of matlab):/

Comment: I added an example of what you need to do, you have to open two compimentary UDP ports as clients, and then send between them. The pseudocode makes this clearer than I can describe it!

Answer (score 1):

Is your script a script m-file or a function?

If it's a function, you'll be losing the scope of the workspace variables which is why it's not working. I'd turn your code into a function like this:

```
  function processRun(run,reset)
    while run ~= 0     % Loop until external reset of 'run' to '0'
      if reset ~= 0
        doReset;   % Reset the parameters for the processing
        reset = 0;
        disp('I did a reset');
      end

      disp('I am processing');
      [run,reset]  =  doProcess;
      pause(1)
    end
```

You can then set the values of run and reset evertime you call the function from VBA.

If you have a script, try removing the run and reset lines from the top, and set their values in the workspace before you run the script. I think you're overwriting your workspace values by running the script file.

Comment: The code itself is the whole content of an m-file. I have a little problem in understanding what your code...if I see it right, I have to call the function processRun(...) once? and then I can change my values in the workspace?

Comment: If you don't have a function definition, I think you might be overwriting your workspace variables in the script. See my edit to my original answer.

Comment: It seems to me that the `reset` variable is being reset to 0 if and only if, for some reason it was changed to 1 in the timespan between the previous check and current check. That reason would be your VBA script and I see no logical problem. A mystery to me.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The only thing I habe trouble with is how to pause (after this reset and then resume) the script when it has been started by run=1 as param...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to make a comment so I'll quote it here:

> @Adam Leadbetter: Thanks, this makes sense. The only thing I habe trouble with is how to pause (after this reset and then resume) the script when it has been started by run=1 as param... – poeschlorn Feb 25 at 7:17

If you want to break out of the loop once reset has been set to one, and then wait for the loop to continue again once `run = 1` that is pretty much the same as just starting over again?

```
function processRun()
run = 1;
while run ~= 1
   run = doProcess();
end
```

if `doProcess()` returns `0` then the function `processRun()` will end (like the behaviour you want to have when reset), the next time `processRun` is called it starts over, with "reset"/default values.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're missing something, then so am I! I think what you've shown here is a more Matlab centric way of the code than the function wrapped one I added.

Comment: hey Juhl, your code is absolutely clear, but I am not convinced that yould solve my problem. In this case the doProcess() needs to get any criteria for aborting the script or returning '0'. This creteria has to come from an external source. My problem is HOW to have access to an external interrupt.